# Jquery animation property not working on my prefered CSS style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a small video game where I want the avatar picture glow red as if taking damage from a npc. To do this effect i'm trying to animate a red shadowBox over my player, but its not working. Can someone help me figure out what i'm dong wrong in particular? I tried using .css but that does not animate it. It only changes it right away.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#usercontainer').click(function() {
        $(this).animate({
        boxShadow: '10px 10px 10px red'
        },'slow');
    });
});
```

Extra CSS + HTML

```
#usercontainer {
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid;
        background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
        }

        #userimage {
            background-color: rgb(0,255,255);
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
            }



<div id="usercontainer">
    <div id="userimage">
        <img src="images/wingedwarrior.jpg" alt="warrior" style="width:200px; height:200px">
            <div id="userHitSplat"> </div>
    </div> <!--END OF USER IMAGE-->
</div><!--END OF USER CONTAINER-->
```

Comment: Would you consider using jQuery UI highlight effect? http://api.jqueryui.com/highlight-effect/

Answer (score 0):

This is probably easier with css animations:

```
#usercontainer {
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid;
        background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: 1s;
        }
#usercontainer.glow {
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px red;
}

        #userimage {
            background-color: rgb(0,255,255);
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
            }
```

And then to animate:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#usercontainer').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('glow');
    });
});
```

The reason the js animation doesn't work is that jquery can't animate colors. Jquery-ui includes the ability to do this, but it's probably not woth it for this when you can use css animations instead.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ry17x6v0/)